# Spring application.yml to resource bundle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have SpringBoot app properties in `application.yml`. 
I am using a third party api, which accepts properties as `ResourceBundle` object only.

How can I convert my `application.yml` to a **`ResourceBundle`** object (preferably with auto-wiring)

Here I wanted to use default application.yml which is loaded by spring, so that I don't want to provide the file name.

Right now, I am thinking of below approach, but hope there's better one (off course, I will inject below as beans,

```
@Bean(name = "appPoperties")
public Properties yamlProperties() throws IOException {
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean bean = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));
    return bean.getObject();
}

ResourceBundleMessageSource rbs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            rbs.setCommonMessages(yamlProperties());

        ResourceBundle rb = new MessageSourceResourceBundle(rbs, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: check this out https://github.com/akihyro/yaml-resource-bundle

Comment: Thanks, that's another approach I was thinking of by extending ResourceBundle. Edited the question - I don't want to pass any filename. I want to use the default loaded yml file with spring.